# php get returning unassigned values

Tags: php, url, get

I have a simple test page that is meant to confirm the GET values

```
<?php
if ($_GET ['car'] = 'yes') {
echo 'You have a car. It is set to: ' . $_GET ['car'] . '<br>';
}
if ($_GET ['boat'] = 'yes') {
echo 'You have a boat. It is set to: ' . $_GET ['boat'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

I am verifying with multiple URL strings:

1. test.php?car=yes&boat=no
2. test.php?car=no&boat=no
3. test.php?car=no&boat=yes
4. test.php?car=yes&boat=yes

If I navigate to the URL "test.php?car=no&boat=no" the echo function prints 'yes' instead of 'no'.

Please assist me in understanding why I am not receiving the desired outcome of 'no' instead of 'yes'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statements are making $_GET['car'] equal to 'yes', instead of checking to see IF $_GET['car'] IS EQUAL TO 'yes'. Try this:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['car'] == 'yes') {
        echo 'You have a car. It is set to: ' . $_GET['car'] . '<br>';
    }
    if ($_GET['boat'] == 'yes') {
        echo 'You have a boat. It is set to: ' . $_GET['boat'] . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: While all the other answers were correct I found this the most easiest to digest. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

**Assignment Operator**

```
$a=$b
```

The basic assignment operator is "=". as "equal to". Don't. 
It really means that the left operand gets set to the value of the expression on the right (that is, "gets set to").

**Comparison Operator**

```
$a == $b 

Results TRUE, if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
```

So, change your code to below code for comparing as you are not assigning.

```
<?php
if ($_GET ['car'] == 'yes') {
echo 'You have a car. It is set to: ' . $_GET ['car'] . '<br>';
}
if ($_GET ['boat'] == 'yes') {
echo 'You have a boat. It is set to: ' . $_GET ['boat'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```